# what sip middleware can I use to modify sip headers

Tags: proxy, udp, sip

my sip provider doesn't support some SIP headers that I need to send to my IP Phones. I can specify my own headers, but my provider add some prefix in front of them everytime.

I need to send Call-info header to my phone. But my provider adds something like X-PH- prefix so my IP phone doesn't understand that modified header.

I need to create some sort of middleware which I'll have between IP phone and Provider's server in my network. Is there any proxy / middleware that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting a Session Border Controller [Sonus, Dialogic etc] with "Header Manipulation Rules" Capabilities. Other options are using Opensips / Kamailio to make the header manipulations, but it has a learning curve for the way the rules are defined and of course the pain of putting it together in the network.

BTW, since you are specifically looking for RFC compliant SIP Headers [Call_info], you can always push for it with the carrier you are dealing with. Get them to comply to the SIP Specs. Maybe they see merit pushing their vendors for compliance.